# how to get input type email's value from jquery

Tags: jquery, selector

I was trying to get the `<input type="email" name="mail">`'s value from `jQuery`.
I've to run a validation for checking `mail`'s value

```
<script>
    function valid(){
        var em = $.trim($('input:email[name=mail]').val());
        if(em.length < 5){
            alert('Please enter email id');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

but the form is still submitting if the user left `mail` blank.
I've gone through [jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/form-selectors/) but not found any `selector` for `email`. Why so?
Why it is not present there and how would I solve this problem?

Comment: Use: `input[type=email][name=mail]`

Comment: @jimjimmy1995: why `input[type=email][name=mail]`? as for others I can do `input:text[name=theirname]` or `input:radio[name=rad]` etc

Comment: @MohammadFaisal HTML5 elements have yet to be added to the jQuery specification.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995: okay. is that the only reason?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Well it's the only reason that matters. You will have to get the element by type or give it an ID for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do:

```
$.trim($("input[name='mail']").val());
```

Comment: why isn't there any selector for `input:email`?

Comment: It is not working ? Is there any other alternative ?

Comment: what if your input element has a different name? forms with multiple input channel contact has a generic name or maybe is using an array method like name="contact[0][email]"

I think troels got a point with this input[type=email]

Answer (score 8):

I see that this is rather old, but I would like to throw my two cents in for the future generations.

While there is not strictly a pseudo selector like `input:email`, there is a type-selector version that works just like the pseudo would: `input[type=email]`

**Extra reading:**

this selector can do alot of cool things like selecting all that starts with an id: `input[id^=prod-]` would select all inputs with an id of prod-X where X could be anything and any length. This is achieved using ^=

Answer (score 2):

In case it ever helps anyone, I had two inputs with same id, but one for mobile and one for desktop. I was testing the desktop and getting no value. Turns out the mobile one although hidden was the input getting selected, thus returning blank.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to get date submitted through form, this will work perfectly fine:

```js
$("input[type = 'date']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend jQuery by this easy function http://markdalgleish.com/2011/05/jquery-selector-for-html5-input-types/ After this you can select all text inputs by calling `$('input:textall');`